# How do i refresh my list view (using base adapter) with two items, whenever data changes from web server?

Tags: android, web-services, listview

How do i refresh my list view (using base adapter) with two items, whenever data changes from web server?
If i had selected any item before refresh, i want it to be selected even after refresh.

Comment: Add new data to list and call notifyDatachanged

Comment: @ram, i want to change the list completely, not adding items

Comment: then what do you mean ""If i had selected any item before refresh, i want it to be selected even after refresh.""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this : `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`